# ios Current Development Certificates going to expire

Tags: iphone, ios, certificate

I am going upload an iPhone app on app store with provisioning profile which going to be expired after 4 days. i.e my Current Development Certificates expires within 4 days.
So my question is should i wait to expire current certificate then renew it and then upload app. or should I upload app now and renewing cetrificate and provisioning profile make my app store app continue to run on users device.
Please Help. Thank you

PN: Please read Distribution Certificate instead Development Certificates..!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upload the app with your current certificate and then renew your certificate. Maybe you even make a few sales in the mean time :)

You're not the first one to go through this. You can imagine that we don't re-release all our apps once the current cert expires.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use a development certificate for uploading iphone app to app store. You need to create a Distribution Profile for adding apps to app store. Please go through iOS developer  guide for more details.

Comment: Sorry it is distribution certificate with distribution profile! So now its your turn.

Comment: You can revoke your existing  iOS
Distribution Certificate in the Apple Developer  or iPhone Provisioning Portal. After your certificate has been
revoked, you can create a new Certificate Signing Request and obtain a new iOS Distribution Certificate.

Comment: So should i have to revoke certificate before it expires? and what about my current apps on app store after revoking? and again what it affects current apps on app store after it expires?

Comment: Revoking iOS Distribution Certificates will NOT affect applications already running on your
device or applications that are already available on the App Store. You can continue to submit application updates to the App
Store with a new iOS Distribution Certificate. However, any applications you have distributed via Ad Hoc Distribution will no
longer run after your iOS Distribution Certificate expires. 

© 2010

Comment: Thank you. Actually I am little bit confused betweeen certificate revoke and renew?

Comment: Login to your developer account, remove the already existing distribution profile and create a new one.

Comment: Sorry, Mahesh - thanks for a great question, and Swapna, thanks for the responses, but it is confusing.  The main reason we are asking questions, is there is precious little documentation in the Provisioning Portal on renewal.  Can you lay out in a step-by-step?  Are you saying we need to revoke our current certificates (both Development and Distribution certs), and then create new ones, then sign our apps with the new ones?